# junit test cannot be resolved to a type after adding junit jar file

Tags: junit4

I want to create a simple Junit test. However, after I buildpath using **Eclipse** for Junit4, it still give me an error:  junit test cannot be resolved to a type for: 
**JunitTesting** class

Please see my screenshot for setting: [image]

[image]

Comment: `JunitTesting` is not a class provided by JUnit4.

Comment: Hi Siking, thank you so much! You are right! i got it. It's was a very stupid mistake I made.